# Give Service more time to shut down

Tags: advanced-installer

From our Advanced Installer setup, we install/upgrade a service that needs up to a minute to shut down. We cannot decrease the time it needs, and it will be shut down after a minute.

If AI tries to stop that service, it comes up with an error message after less than a minute ("The setup was unable to automatically close all requested applications. Please ensure that the applications holding files in use are closed before continuing with the installation").

I have not found an option in Advanced Installer Professional to change the timeout of the wait.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. You can try to use a custom action to stop the service. That means you could write your own code to trigger a service stop operation and wait for a minute. This code can be executed as a custom action.

To make sure the described error message is not thrown you should execute your custom action before "Paths Resolution" action.